# Why does my function works in the HTML file but not in JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I'm creating a web page that has a text area in it and the user can enter code and have it displayed underneath. If I place my function in the HTML file it works just fine but when I move it to the JS file it doesn't work. Any help, even pointing me in the direction of my issue would be appreciated. 
Here is my HTML code with the function commented out......

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>DOM TREE 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Content.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/js01.js"></script> 
</head>

<body style="background-color:lightgray" id="bd">
<div id="third">
    <h1> DOM TREE <img src="Images/tree_logo.jpg" alt="Calc" id = "pic">
</h1>
    <form id="DOMForm">

    <textarea id="myTextarea" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>

    <p><button type="button" onclick="AddFunction()">Add Content</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="Change()">Change Style</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="Clear()">Clear Content</button>
    </p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

<!--<script>
function AddFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script> -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS file with the function.....

```
function AddFunction() 
{
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
function changestyle() 
{

}

function clear() 
{
    document.getElementById("DomForm").reset(); 
}
```

Comment: Check the console in the develop tools for errors messages. Is your JS file in the proper location? You also appear to be calling a function named change `onclick="Change()"` but haven't defined one (you do have one named `changestyle` though). Javascript is case-sensitive, so `Clear()` won't call `function clear`

Comment: @Pytth — The HTML clearly shows the `onclick` attributes which trigger the function calls.

Comment: Yeah the clear function works just fine so I know that the JS file is in the right location

Comment: There seem to be a lot of issues with uppercase/lowercase... Make sure this is consistent.

Comment: **Aside note:** [javascript-standard-style](https://standardjs.com/rules.html#javascript-standard-style)

Comment: "clear function works just fine"... then there must be a difference between the code you're showing us, and the code you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

Because names are different, compare `onclick="Change()"` to `function changestyle()` and `onclick="Clear()"` to `function clear()`.

Comment: Close, but probably the OP is facing another problem because s/he stated *Not sure why my function works in the HTML file but not in JS file*.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. I noticed that right after I posted the question. Thanks again. That fixed it.